# GRAILS + ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, grails, plugins

I wanna add Grails plugin for my SDK Eclipse 3.5.2. I try Install New Software using this repo; http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e3.5/ but it gives an error. How can I do that?

THX

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.1.0.20101020-2100-e35-release (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.20101020-2100-e35-release)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Java Development Tools Core 3.5.2.v_981_R35x (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.5.2.v_981_R35x)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.5.1.v_972_R35x (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.5.1.v_972_R35x)

Comment: Java Development Tools Core 3.5.2.20101020-2100-e35-release (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.5.2.20101020-2100-e35-release)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.5.2.v_981_R35x]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [3.5.2.r352_v20100108-7r88FEwFH4SRsd9dz0fZ6z-rwffZ]

Comment: Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.1.0.20101020-2100-e35-release (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.20101020-2100-e35-release)
    To: org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group [2.1.0.20101020-2100-e35-release]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From Patch: org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group 2.1.0.20101020-2100-e35-release Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.5.2.r352_v20100108-7r88FEwFH4SRsd9dz0fZ6z-rwffZ (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.5.2.r352_v20100108-7r88FEwFH4SRsd9dz0fZ6z-rwffZ)
To: org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.5.2.20101020-2100-e35-release]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the window where you have chosen what you want to install and it begins the install it checks dependencies and other things. In your case you have chosen two conflicting Java installs.

Java Development Tools Core 3.5.2.v_981_R35x 
and 
Java Development Tools Core 3.5.1.v_972_R35x

uncheck the v_972 and go with the higher release.